# Can a manifest-managed resource fall back to its own cached copy when offline?

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I'm using an HTML5 manifest to allow an application to work offline.  I have a resource -- say */background.png* -- that may update from time to time, but if the application is offline, the last-retrieved version is suitable for use.  The behavior I want is for the browser to request */background.png* normally if it's online, but to fall back to the cached version if the request fails because it's offline, the server is down, etc.

In my testing, having a manifest entry like

```
NETWORK:
/background.png
```

made the browser *always* try to request the resource. It would return an error, rather than returning a copy from the appcache, if it was offline.  That's not what I want, but it is how NETWORK is supposed to behave as I understand it.

I also tried

```
FALLBACK:
/background.png /background.png
```

hoping that might mean "fall back to the cache copy if you can't get a new one", but in that configuration the browser doesn't try to request the resource if it's online.

Another possibility I considered was

```
CACHE:
/offline-background.png

FALLBACK:
/background.png /offline-background.png
```

but having two different names for the same resource -- and having the same resource requested twice (once for the *img src="background.png"* and once for the cached offline copy) -- seemed like an unattractive hack.

I could also make an arbitrary change to the manifest when *background.png* changes, but that would cause the browser to check everything in the manifest.

Is it possible to get this "use what I have unless I can get a new one" pattern from an HTML5 manifest? This seems like a reasonable pattern, so I'd think there'd be a clean way to do it. If not, can anyone suggest another approach?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The original question referred to "news.json", implying that the resource was being retrieved by JavaScript, but I've changed it to "background.png" to make it clearer that I'd like to do this with any resource used by a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to manage the caching yourself is to stick it into [local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).  You should be able to simply drop the JSON from your news feed straight into a single variable.  When you request the `/news.json` file only update the cached copy of it on a `200` response, in the rest of your app always use the copy in local storage.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion.  That approach will work for things requested by AJAX -- which my choice of resource name in the original question certainly implied.  But I'm trying to solve the problem for *any* resource that could be used by the page, including a simple image reference, where there's no JavaScript involved.  I'd love to be able to use this nice new offline cache feature rather than "roll my own" with offline storage. I edited the question to refer to "background.png" instead of "news.json" to clarify the intent. Thanks again!

Comment: @jgarbers Then it's not going to work.  If you list the file in the manifest then it will be served from the application cache.  It won't be updated from the server until you update the manifest file itself.  The way it's designed to work it: unchanging things go in the manifest; changing things (ie. data) are requested by AJAX and you handle the caching of them yourself.  If you want the image to be data driven, consider using `canvas` or `svg`.

Comment: I'm still curious why the design doesn't support what I think is a reasonable pattern -- "use what you have if you're offline, but check for a new one if you aren't" -- but I'll accept your answer. It may not be what I wanted to hear, but it's right!